# A Fountain of Colors

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, knowledge, movies

### A Fountain of Colors

---

A rock overlooks as my garden unfurls.

His pebble admires as the nice sky, it swirls.

The odd-looking pink one is chipper today.

The lily exposes when Chopin I play.

There's one that is orange (or copper) in hue.

The yellow one listens intently to you.

The Kraspedia's distant, does it make a sound?

The blue one is wilted; another's turned brown.

> So the question is: What's so special about my garden?

EDIT: fixed typos: "at" in the second line to "as," as intended, and uncapitalized "Lily," to avoid confusion. (the capitalization was not a hint!)

EDIT 2: After [a little research](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags), I added two tags [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) and [trivia](/questions/tagged/trivia).

EDIT 3: Another tag added, chiseling down the [trivia](/questions/tagged/trivia) tag: [movies](/questions/tagged/movies).

Hint:

> Notice the six colors used (including *lily*), maybe this particular combination will seem familiar.

Comment: Did you mean Craspedia??

Comment: @PaigeMeinke It's a mystery, isn't it!

Comment: You have magical pebbles that are able to admire the sky!

Comment: +1 for riddle-poem which picks a metre and sticks with it!  :)

Comment: I have added an answer. Am i on the right track ?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/another-sensational-crime-fiction You would like this question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your garden contains

> Characters of **Reservoir Dogs**

Because

> The main characters in that movie are 
>
> Mr. Brown
> Mr. White
> Mr. Pink
> Mr. Blue
> Mr. Orange
> Mr. Blonde (lily)
> Joe Cabot
> The cop
> The nice guy
> K-Billy
>
>
> And you are talking about their characteristics.

A rock overlooks as my garden unfurls.

> I think this refers to Joe Cabot, the mastermind behind the jewel heist

His pebble admires as the nice sky, it swirls.

> Rock's pebble, his son Eddie Cabot is the **Nice Guy** in the beginning of the movie and he is not a Nice guy afterwards.

The odd-looking pink one is chipper today.

> Mr. Pink is happy because he got the diamond.

There's one that is orange (or copper) in hue.

> Mr. Orange is the undercover **cop**

The yellow one listens intently to you

> Mr. White is a veteran gangster and a silent person.

The Kraspedia's distant, does it make a sound?

> Refers to the hostage (Cop) who's mouth is taped and cannot speak. Kraspedia(craspedia) refers to K-billy buttons, simply K-Billy, which is a fictional radio character.

The lily exposes when Chopin I play.

> There is a scene in that movie in which Mr. Blonde **chopping** cop's ear while **play**ing music.

The blue one is wilted; another's turned brown.

> Mr Brown and Blue were getting killed in that movie.

*And the title : **A Fountain of Colors***

> Reservoir refers to source of water, a fountain in the garden.

Comment: Your overall answer is right, but some of the justification is off... You seem to be rot13(zvkvat hc lryybj/Oybaqr jvgu Yvyl/Juvgr) and [Kraspedia](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kraspedia) is not another allusion to "Yellow." It is misspelled *why?*

Comment: @Chowzen made the changes, still lacking the Kraspedia. Is that mean rot13(xrebfrar) ?

Comment: The yellow clue is still getting a white response and vice-versa... The K is a character that hasn't been identified in your "Because" spoiler. BTW: the nice sky, it *swirl*s rot13(rqql)

Comment: @Chowzen I never thought this could be this much deep. I watched this years before and collecting data from internet now. Anyways i think i fixed all except the white-yellow, which still i am thinking about.

Comment: You've earned the ✓ ! Eventually (if you don't mind), I'll edit and explain some of the last tidbits.

Comment: @Chowzen Sure :)

Answer (score 6):

Your garden is special because

> It's drawn in chalk.

I figured it out because

> Of the capital letters in the riddle's text which spell chalk.

And the rocks are

> Pieces of chalk of different colors.

Comment: Amazing coincidence that the capitals (if you ignore all the "T"s) spelled "CHALK." I changed the "L" to a small "l" (it wasn't necessary), but left the "K" as is (a genus or species should be capitalized, even if it is misspelled :) ). +1 for a nice guess!

Comment: Aw man, I totally thought that was intentional. I thought it made so much sense given the context of rocks and colors. :(

Comment: This has to be the most amazing unintentional solution ever :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your garden is

> The day

A rock overlooks as my garden unfurls.

> The sun observes as the day begins

His pebble admires as the nice sky, it swirls.

> The moon overlooks the starry night as in the famous painting by van Gogh, hence the swirls.

The lily exposes when Chopin I play.

> Chopin was famous by his nocturnes, but lillies are oftentimes white/pink with spots, so maybe references the transitition from night to morning (?)

The odd-looking pink one is chipper today.

> The morning sky looks pink in the early hours of the sunrise

There's one that is orange (or copper) in hue.

> Twilight is mostly orange

The yellow one listens intently to you.

> The sun is directly on top of you at midday, so he listens (?)

The Kraspedia's distant, does it make a sound?

> Sun looks like a giant bulb and it is distant (?)

The blue one is wilted; another's turned brown.

> The blue sky fades to brown as the night falls, another day is gone

It's a bit of a stretch because I can't figure out some of the clues.

Comment: Not it, but another interesting idea. Check out my newest EDIT above.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely satisfied with this, but much of it fits.

Your garden is ...

> The planets of our solar system

A rock overlooks as my garden unfurls.

> Earth overlooking the rest of the "garden"

His pebble admires as the nice sky, it swirls.

> The moon is Earth's "pebble" admiring the swirling atmosphere of earth.  Or the "swirl" of the planets travelling in their orbits

The odd-looking pink one is chipper today.

> Mars is red which could be described as "odd-looking pink"

The lily exposes when Chopin I play.

> Mercury.  Chopin is a named crater on Mercury.  I don't know how Lily fits in.

There's one that is orange (or copper) in hue.

> Jupiter is orange

The yellow one listens intently to you.

> Venus appears yellow due to sulfur clouds

The Kraspedia's distant, does it make a sound?

> Saturn.  The planet appears yellow, like craspedias.  In addition, the Cassini spacecraft detected "sounds" (radio waves) when it passed Saturn.  No explanation for the misspelling (Or eastern European spelling)

The blue one is wilted; another's turned brown.

> Uranus and Neptune.  They each appear blue due to Methane gas.  Uranus' axis is tilted (wilted).  No explanation for Neptune being brown.  Pluto is brown, but that leaves out Neptune.

Comment: Pretty good, much of it fits! The actual answer will fit everything, though, from the title to the misspelled flower name to the chipper to the 'nice sky' and everything else. I'm adding a hint, see the edit..