# Nine Pieces of Gold on One Boat

Tags: riddle, wordplay

There were four cats and three dogs. A house with no lights and nothing around for miles. There was one road that lead to nowhere. There was one plane that only had one wing. In the house there were two murderers. One with a knife and one with a gun. The two murderers were opposite. One murderer was forty three. One of the murderers initials were JO. What was the other murderer's age and what were his initials.

Comment: @Chowzen Are you sure the edit is wise? I think what you thought was a misphrasing was intended by the OP.

Comment: @Untitpoi [From Rubio's comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/another-sensational-crime-fiction), "the original poster can always roll them back, if [the editor has] done unintentional harm."

Comment: Having seen the correct answer, I'm curious what you meant by the title, the cats/dogs, and the house. Typically, riddles tie in these elements with the answer as well.

Comment: @Phylyp "... and there was a Red Herring Farm..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ages are

> 43 and 34

and the initials are

> OJ and JO

This is because

> They are opposite. So JO to OJ and 43 to 34.